# What is this weird variant on a 6-pin power supply connector called?

Tags: power-supply, connector, cables

I need more power connections for SATA hard drives than the one SATA power cable that came with my Apevia ATX-GX650W semi-modular power supply provides. I thought I'd just use another seemingly similar 6-pin-3-SATA left over from another power supply. But it wasn't compatible.

[image: 6-pin-3-SATA power cable]

On the left is the 6-pin connector that works, on the right what came with my other power supply, and the only thing that, as far as I can tell, the rest of the world uses.

[image: 6-pin connector close-ups]

Everything I've found online about 6-pin power connectors, if a close-up view of the connector or a pinout diagram is provided, shows the type of connector on the right.

I can't find anything like the connector on the left, with three square pins on top and three notched pins on the bottom. Not even Apevia sells extra cables with connectors like that on their own website.

Comment: Duplicate question on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/1781734/are-there-different-kinds-of-sata-power-connectors-and-if-so-what-terminology .  StackExchange discourages cross-posting to multiple stacks.

Comment: It's a related question, but I'm asking the question in a different way, with extra details I didn't have before, and to a different audience with different skills. I think this is a valid variation, and not an out-right duplicate.

Comment: My initial thought was to close this question as *off-topic, migrate to SuperUser*.  But then I noticed that you've posted the question to SuperUser already.

Comment: My search for further info, since SuperUser wasn't providing much help, actually led me to believe that very specific connector details were more in the bailiwick of electrical engineers.

Comment: You can buy any Molex or clone connector with any keying you like. There is no standard how the PSU end of computer cables should look like or what their pinout should be.

Answer (score 1):

Probably proprietary to prevent using an incompatible cable and blowing up the attached devices; you can see that at least two of the pins are different.  I can't find a pinout of that specific connector on the left, but I *can* find an article called "Mixing Modular PSU Cables Can Kill Components", which supports the theory.

Comment: It's a shame their doesn't seem to be any commonly-used nomenclature to distinguish these connector types. And if it's just Apevia being proprietary for the sake of being proprietary, it's very odd they don't sell extra cables that match.

Comment: I don't believe there's a standard that covers modular power supply cables' attachment to the power supply.  Maybe they just had a bunch of those connectors laying around (à la Centronics 36-pin), or maybe it was proprietary for the sake of proprietary.  Apevia appears be a more shall we say "budget" manufacturer compared to e.g. Corsair, which does sell replacement modular cables.  The juice might not be worth the squeeze for them.

Comment: Without finding the article, I can vouch for "Mixing Modular PSU Cables Can Kill Components". They are not standardized at the PSU end and swapping 5V and 12V is fatal to things like hard disk drives.